# Converting all columns of the table into the moving averages along rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe, df, with index as date column and the columns with integers.

```
c = {'Date': ['2020-12-08','2020-12-09','2020-12-10','2020-12-11','2020-12-12','2020-12-13','2020-12-14'], 'Name1': [11,5,85,128,4,3,233], 'Name2':[18,1,39,63,2,3,330],'Name3':[15,32,80,89,54,70,89], 'Name4' :[1,2,5,75,4,1,25], 'Name5':[394,937,840,788,259,241,718], 'Name6':[66,96,118,43,31,27,50], 'Name7':[34,67,72,76,0,0,151]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=c).set_index('Date')
df

Date        Name1 Name2 Name3   .... Name7                                                                      
...
2020-12-08  11    18     15     
2020-12-09  5     1      32     
2020-12-10  85    39     80     
2020-12-11  128   ...
2020-12-12  4     ...
2020-12-13  3     ...
2020-12-14  233   ...
```

and I want to get moving averages on each column.

I have tried it on 1 column which is fine - it gives the first 6 nans following by the 7-day averages.

```
df_a = (df['Name1'].rolling(7)).mean()
df_a.tail(10)
2020-12-08           NaN
2020-12-09           NaN
2020-12-10           NaN
2020-12-11           NaN
2020-12-12           NaN
2020-12-13           NaN
2020-12-14     67.000000
2020-12-15    132.857143
....
```

Now, I'm trying to do the same for all of the columns

```
cols= ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5','Name6','Name7']

df_a = df.apply(lambda x: (x[cols].rolling(7)).mean(), axis=1)
```

and it gives me something like this - nan for the first 6 columns.

```
Date               Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name Name6 Name7
2020-12-08         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   77
2020-12-09         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   163
2020-12-10         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   177
2020-12-11         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   180
2020-12-12         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   51
```

How can I amend the above so it gives me the rolling averages row-wise?

Comment: Do you want rolling mean for all the Dataframe columns, or just selective columns?

Comment: i updated the question so you can reproduce.  for all the dataframe columns, yes.

Comment: Then simply using `df.rolling(7).mean()` would be suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your `Date` column is already the row index. As such, you can simply use:

```
df.rolling(7).mean()
```

If your `Date` column is not already the row index, you can try:

```
df.set_index('Date').rolling(7).mean()
```

Comment: @bluetail  Yes, it's easily overlooked.  Bear in mind that Pandas functions often have 2 versions:  one for Dataframe and one for Series.  So, make good use of the Pandas API guide to lookup if any relevant functions.